# How to rewrite this php function into HTML-emeddable function <?php ?>

Tags: php, html

Could someone convert this line of code to be readable by HTML?

```
echo '<h3>'. $r['title'] .'</h3>';
```

into something like this:

```
<?php echo...blah blah blah ?>     /* To display the title in HTML  */
```

I am sure I am not doing it right, that's why it's still not working :(.

Edit: There seems to be a confusion here. I am *not* going to modify the original php function. What I need to do is **call it** to my HTML page, to display the **Title** of the page

Comment: You'll need to be a little more explicit in what you're asking. You want to call a function called r, passing in an argument of title, and somehow it needs to guess what title you want displaying. The r() function isn't even going to be aware of what $r is.

Comment: How is it not working? What do you see, or not see?

Comment: Have you tested $r with print_r?

Comment: If you need to call it in your HTML, you'll need something like Ajax. However, given the simplicity of the function, why not simply use a javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah you mean?

```
<php echo "&lt;h3&gt;$r['title']&lt;/h3&gt;"; ?>
```

could be an answer to this unclear question

Answer (score 1):

```
function r($text, $level = 3)
{
    $tag = 'h' . $level . '>';
    return '<' . $tag . $text . '</' . $tag;
}
```

**Thanks for the downvote. The given question is totally unclear and constantly edited.**

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: I've updated my question. Basically I need it rewritten into this form: <? php echo.......

Comment: This function works just like you want it to in the example you gave. If you want something else you need to add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Save the result into a variable.

```
<?php $title = '<h3>'. $r['title'] .'</h3>';?>

<?php echo $title; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but you can't use PHP code within an HTML page.

The line

```
<?php echo '<h3>'. $r['title'] .'</h3>'; ?>
```

Within a PHP file, will print out the  contents of `$r['title']`, within `<h3>` tags.

There is no function involved; `$r` is an associative array variable and `title` is a key to a particular value.